# Build dll without /clr option

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

In visual studio 2005 how to compile without the /clr option?
visual studio project properties->Configuration properties->C/C++ ->Command Line->All options: here the /clr switch is enabled by default with many other options, however i am unable to edit this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project Properties on the General tab you should see a section for Project Defaults. Change **Common Language Runtime Support** to **No Common Language Runtime Support**

Answer (score 3):

Just from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx).
Configuration Properties -> Common Language Runtime Support. Set it to "No support".

On the other hand how did you manage to enable this with a C++ project.

Comment: It's on by default for certain wizard generated C++ applications. VS2005 introduced C++/CLI so they did this I think to try and get us to use it ;-)

Comment: @AJG85: Thanks. I was just curious. I usually don't use the GUI. I am still using makefiles most of the time.